# Smart TV API for remote control by IP, Official documentation

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv

I have found some links where I have read how to make pairing and control Samsung smart TV in local network using IP:

https://community.smartthings.com/t/samsung-smart-tv-support/741/71

https://community.smartthings.com/t/samsung-tv-support-in-smartthings/22364/87

But, when I make 2nd step (sending post request with PIN code) I receive 400 Bad request.

I tryed to find official documenatation with instructions, but I have not found it. Can anyone help me? Thank you.